# Path of a script and its execution time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need a script with process `ps aux` and `etime` to see the path of the scripts and time of execution on Linux. `ps aux etime` does not work.

What should I use to learn path of a script and its execution time?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output through AWK and get just the 10th and 11th columns.

```
 ps aux | awk '{ print $10"\t"$11 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ps -eo cmd,etime` ?